# Duvida Springboot + RestFul

Tags: java, spring-boot, restful

estou tendo um problema com minhas solicitações Rest.

Até um tempo atras meu código estava funcionando normalmente, porem, um a duas semanas atras, minhas requisições param de funcionar, exceto os métodos GET e Delete

```
GET 
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/estabelecimentos", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
        public @ResponseBody List<Estabelecimento> getAllEst() {
            return er.findAll();
        }

Delete
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/api/estabelecimentos/{id}", produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<Estabelecimento> deleteEst(@PathVariable Long id) {
            er.deleteById(id);
            return new ResponseEntity<Estabelecimento>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Os demais métodos (POST e PUT) me retornam erro 415 via client (Postman) e no log do springboot recebo esse retorno;

```
POST
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/estabelecimentos", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Estabelecimento> newEstabelecimento(@RequestBody Estabelecimento estabelecimento) {
        er.save(estabelecimento);
        return new ResponseEntity<Estabelecimento>(estabelecimento, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

PUT
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/api/estabelecimentos/{id}", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updadeEstabelecimento(@RequestBody Estabelecimento esta, @PathVariable Long id){
        Optional<Estabelecimento> estab = er.findById(id);

        if(!estab.isPresent()) 
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();

        esta.setCod_Estabelecimento(id);
        er.save(esta);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

Log Springboot
14:24:36.716  WARN 14320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.api.Entity.Estabelecimento]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'
2019-05-22 14:24:36.720  WARN 14320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.api.Entity.Estabelecimento]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'
2019-05-22 14:24:36.724  WARN 14320 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Retorno Clien(Postman)
"timestamp": "2019-05-22T17:24:36.740+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:224)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:157)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgumen
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz ? não consegui encontrar nada na internet

Comment: Manda o Corpo da requisição e manda a entidade Estabelecimento tbm

Comment: *um a duas semanas atras, minhas requisições param de funcionar* - Que alteração você realizou nessas duas semanas para parar de funcionar?

Comment: Poderia postar as entidades Estabelecimento e as suas sub-entidades que são como atributos, porque esse erro deve ser alguma referencia ciclica, onde o pai chama o filho, que em seguida o filho chama o pais ou o filho tem mais de um pai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro que realmente importa na stacktrace é este:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'
```

Você possui ou adicionou a annotation `@JsonBackReference` ou `@JsonManagedReference` em sua entidade de forma incorreta.

Utilize `@JsonManagedReference` para coleções e `@JsonBackReference` para relacionamentos simples.

---

Sobre o `415 - Unsupported Media Type`, isso foi discutido [nesta](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11763) e [nesta](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20141) thread do Spring, concordo que não é o melhor tratamento de erro para um erro de parse (em minha opinião deveria ser 422).

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma.

Apos analisar a resposta do Nullptr, consegui compreender melhor do que se tratava

adicionei um value para as classes com relacionamento

Ex:
Classe A
@JsonManagedReference(value = "nome-de-identificação")

Classe B
@JsonBackReference(value = "nome-de-identificação")

Comment: não esquece de marcar minha resposta como correta :)

Comment: haha' desculpe!
Marcado!